# How do I get the URL for Google Map embedded on my website?

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps

I am displaying a map on a website using the Google Map API. I want to include a link on that same page to take them directly to the map on Google Maps.

Is there an API call I can make to the map to retrieve the URL of either the current location/zoom level or the starting location/zoom level?

Comment: How are you displaying the map? Don't you use the same URL to display map?

Comment: With the API you don't need to have a URL, you just set latitude and longitude and the map displays in your specified DIV element. I'm trying to get the URL that would display that map without the API.

Comment: I ended up using information given by two of the answers. In the end I used jQuery and retrieved the information from the map object to create a new URL passed into window.open.

`window.open("http://maps.google.com/?ll="+map.getCenter().toUrlValue()+"&z="+map.getZoom()+"&t="+map.getCurrentMapType().getUrlArg(), "largermap");`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is the link to use to centre Google Maps to a point:

```
http://maps.google.com/?ll=LATITUDE,LONGITUDE&z=ZOOM
```

All you need to do is to replace the above `LATITUDE`, `LONGITUDE` and `ZOOM` with the required coordinates.

---

To get the latitude and longitude where the mouse is clicked, you could use the following API code:

```
var map = new GMap2(document.getElementById("map_canvas"));

GEvent.addListener(map,"click", function(overlay, latlng) {     
   if (latlng) { 
      // latlng defines the latitude and longitude where the mouse was clicked.
   }
});
```

Comment: is there an API for this? so, will this change in the future or is it something they are set to support in the future? will I have code that magically breaks in the future if I code against this?

Comment: It is the same format used when you click on the `LINK` button in Google Maps, so it should not change since people use these as permanent links.

Comment: Wikipedia GeoHack, which is used to display the location of countries and cities, uses this format for Google Maps. Try: http://stable.toolserver.org/geohack/geohack.php?pagename=Malta&params=35_53_N_14_30_E_type:country(316)

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to use the API.  From Google maps, click the `Link` link in the upper right corner, and copy the code for `Paste HTML to embed in website` and throw that in your page and it should be what you want.  It puts in the link to see the larger map on Google maps.  You can also click the `Customize and preview embedded map` link to see more options.  It will display your map at whatever zoom and location you set it to.

Comment: I was hoping to have this dynamic. I currently have the lat/long so I am hoping to get the link, either by creating the link from lat/long or retrieving it from the map.

Comment: so obvious that sometimes we just can't see it

Answer (score 2):

This should give you all the query parameters you could want:
http://mapki.com/wiki/Google_Map_Parameters

Then just make a link pointing at `maps.google.com?<INSERT_PARAMS_HERE>`

Comment: does Google have this specified anywhere?

Comment: Yes.  See the link above;  it specifies the available parameters.